# Parsing and Restructuring Emails

Tags: forms, parsing, email

I'm looking for ideas on a method to parse and restructure a block of text received via email to a formed structure. The structure of this block of text does not contain any delimiters and is one continuous string containing different data properties. The structure is usually always the same, however it can present differently.

Example string 1:

```
SOME TWP 123 SOME RD THIS RD / THAT RD PROBLEM brief details MAP# UNIT# TIME
```

Example string 2:

```
I123 NB MM 50 I 123 SB, I 123 SB / I 123 NB PROBLEM brief details MAP# UNIT# TIME
```

I want to restructure these and resend the restructured form as such:

Example form 1:

```
    AREA: SOME TWP
    ADDRESS: 123 SOME RD
    CROSS: THIS RD / THAT RD
    TYPE: PROBLEM
    DETAIL: brief details
    MAP: MAP#
    UNIT: UNIT#
    TIME: TIME
```

Example form 2:

```
    AREA: I123
    ADDRESS: NB MM 50
    CROSS: I 123 SB, I 123 SB / I 123 NB
    TYPE: PROBLEM
    DETAIL: brief details
    MAP: MAP#
    UNIT: UNIT#
    TIME: TIME
```

I can not change any values in the string received, it comes as it comes. I'm more or less looking for a program or scripting language I should be looking into.

I assume I will need something to go through the string from beginning to end and as it finds matches it will add them to the form in the correct area.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with Python, Ruby, PHP, or Perl?  If so, (or even if you are using a different language,) I would think about looking into something called "[regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)".  One of the hard parts of the string you are parsing, however, will be the fact that there are no delimiters (other than spaces, I assume...) which may make this sort of parsing near impossible (i.e. Where does a section begin? Where does a section end?)

Comment: I'm familiar with PHP, though if necessary I have no problem diving into another language. Do you have a specific recommendation on a method of approach most appropriate for this kind of task? There are only really 4 different overall structures for the strings, though occasionally some variables may be omitted such as CROSS or MAP, which may throw a wrench into a parser.

Comment: But how would you detect that `SOME TWP` is `AREA` and not like `I123 NB` where  `I123` is `AREA` and `NB` is start of `ADDRESS`. Only having spaces, means that you need to detect some other rules to split! Do you have some rules what is allowed for the fields?

Comment: `AREA` will most always be 2 words. `I123 NB` would be acceptable as an `AREA` which would make all `AREA`s 2 words. `ADDRESS` will be more complicated, as these can be normal addresses, intersections, or in the case of `I123 NB` could be `MM 50`. `CROSS` gets even murkier, where the strings can supply 0-4 cross streets, with different formatting depending on the number of streets listed. `TYPE` can be string matched reliably from a list. `DETAIL` is a wildcard, nothing in this field can be anticipated beforehand. `MAP` `UNIT` can be matched from a list, and `TIME` is formatted as ##:##

Comment: I also forgot to add `NAME` to the variable list. Strings will contain a "common name" if the address listed is a business or community. Example: `SOME TWP 1ST NATIONAL BANK 123 SOME RD`

Comment: You say `I123 NB` would be acceptable as an `AREA` but in your sample just `I123` is the `AREA`. Even if you sample is wrong. How do you want to detect if it is a 1, 2 or 3 word. So parsing alone would not work you would need to have an database with all valid `AREA`, `ADDRESS`, `CROSS` combinations. And to know if `NAME`is there you would need to know that it is a company, how do you want to detect this? `MAP`, `UNIT` and `TIME` you can parse beginning at the end. But for the rest it is very likely that it would fail.

Comment: Are these strings located anywhere else other than in email?  *(Perhaps some sort of database... or file?)*